# Surface area of a 2-sphere in Abstract Index Notation

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, tensors, spherical-geometry

I believe the following completely specify a 2-sphere of radius 1 in AIN:
$$ R_{ijkl}=\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl} \\
   R_{ij}=g_{ij}\\
   R_{ii}=g_{ii}=2 $$
It is easy enough to determine the area by dropping into a coordinate system and doing a concrete integral, but it seems all the relevant information is available at the abstract level. However, it is not clear to me what techniques would show this without a concrete coordinate system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*First*: The two-sphere is actually not the only surface which admits a metric with constant positive curvature. There's also the [real projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) which is $S^2/\{\pm 1\}$, the two-sphere with antipodal points identified.

*Second*: There is a nice formula relating the area, the curvature, and precisely which (topological) type of surface you're working with.

Let $\chi(M)$ be the [Euler characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic) of $M$. For $M = S^2$ this is $2$, for the same reason as $V-E+F = 2$ for polyhedra. For $M = \mathbb{RP}^2$, this is $1$ (basically because $S^2$ maps two-to-one to it, so if you draw vertices, edges, and faces on it, you'll get twice as many of each back on $S^2$).

Let $K$ be the [Gaussian curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature). Here this is $1$ for the curvature tensor you describe.

Then the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss-Bonnet_theorem) states that $$\int_M K dA = 2 \pi \chi(M)$$

Thus in your case the LHS is $\int_M 1\, dA = \mathrm{Area}(M)$ and the RHS is $2\pi\chi(M)$ which is $4\pi$ for the sphere and $2\pi$ for $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

(There are variants of this for surfaces with boundary and for manifolds in higher dimensions.)

Comment: Very clever! I never would have thought to use Gauss-Bonnet. (+1)

Comment: Is the full Riemann curvature tensor the same for the real projective plane as for the 2-sphere as well or just the scalar curvature? I am guessing it is the same since locally the metric is given by the angle in the ambient euclidean space, which would make the RPP and the 2-sphere are indistinguishable locally. Correct?

Comment: Yes, they have the same full tensor. As you say, they have local patches that are isometric, so they have the same curvature tensor in compatible coordinates. One way to think about this: The real projective plane is the quotient of the sphere by an isometry, so the metric from the sphere gives a metric on the quotient.